How can I mirror/snap an un-centred structure?
It's probably a very simple procedure but, as I am a noob at best, I cannot find any how to do this.
Our structure originates from a 3D scan, which is then cleaned-up by using Quad Remesh then aligned in a specific way to xyz axis for our work purpose.
Sometimes, when there is damage or deformation to one side of the scan, it is necessary to reconstruct the damaged area using duplicate and mirrored geometry.
As you can see, alignment is my problem.
Is there a way to snap-align the mirrored duplicate?
The example I have used here is a simple tube, although some of our scans have much more complex geometry.


You can use a Mirror modifier with another object(like an empty) to control the axis and origin of the mirroring:

Note that I enabled Bisect on the same mirror axis to cut and merge the geometry. You can of course apply the modifier when you are happy with the result.
You could as well manipulate the origin of the object into correct location and orientation and use Symmetrize(Mesh menu in Edit mode) operation in edit mode. Affect Only Origins is useful for manipulating the origin of your object:

If you choose to manually duplicate and mirror the geometry by scaling it by negative amount(you have to keep in mind normals are inverted then and have to take care of them( Alt  +  N  calls Normals menu in edit mode)), you can also precisely position it using snapping functionality. unfortunately, snapping functionality is quite extensive and difficult to explain in a single answer. See the manual and consider watching some video tutorials for that. It works together with transform pivot settings and is quite powerful for pretty much whatever you might need so it's worth learning about.
If you only need to mirror part of your object and then merge it to the rest of your object, it gets a bit complicated and all kinds of modelling techniques might be needed, so that scenario is hard to help with, unless you share the specific model and ask about some specific case. You could ask another more specific question and share your model using https://blend-exchange.com/. It might be a bit tricky to get help with that on Blender Stack Exchange, because it needs to be specific, but it also cannot be too localized and apply only for that situation to be a good question for BSE. You might want to consider asking on Blenderartists.org forums if you struggle to get help here. But plenty of modelling questions like that technically not matching BSE guidelines get answered here as well.

If you need more specifics, I can edit the answer, let me know.
